# How to receive/handle multitouch input in Tcl/Tk?

Tags: tcl, multi-touch, tk-toolkit

My goal is to be able to use my laptop's touchscreen as an input device for my desktop.

My ideal course of action would be to run a fullscreen Tk program on the laptop and receive touchscreen input into it, and use sockets to forward that data to a server on the desktop which would translate the input into Windows events using TWAPI.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that Tk handles multitouch; as far as I can tell it treats the input like a mouse.  Am I wrong, or is that the state of things?  Are there any good options for this functionality in Tcl?

Comment: Excellent question. Don't know; I don't have Tk on hardware which supports multitouch…

Comment: I'm sure it is possible using twapi and/or Ffidl. But I don't have any multitouch device with Tk.